# How can I pass a big html code block to a with variable in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm looking to pass a big html code block value to a with variable. How can I achieve that elegantly?

Example:

```
{% include "includes/template.html" with info="big html code block" %}
```

I'm wondering how I can accomplish this elegantly. One option would be to escape all quotes and new lines. Is there any other better way to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate _what_ functionality you're trying to accomplish, not _how_? You've already extracted reusable code into includable template. Why would you pass something additional into it as a "big html code block"? Where do you get this block from? From DB?

Comment: Here is an example:

`{% block details_column_1 %}`
`{% include "includes/column_details.html" with detail_title="Customer Name:" detail_info="Tom" %}`
`{% endblock details_column_1 %}`

Above, that include signify a single table row and I supply value with "with". However sometime the value can be html. For example, if I want to pass the detail_info with anchor tag or some formatting with div and classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) template tag

It stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block tag.

```
{% verbatim %}
    {% include "includes/template.html" with info=big_html_code %}
{% endverbatim %}
```

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly how it works.